# C# Entity Framework 6 with npgsql postgresql custom data type not mapped in edmx

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql, ef-database-first

I use Entity Framework 6 with a database-first approach with `postgresql` (npgsql). I have this table with column that has custom data type (domains) in `postgresql`:

[image: table with custom data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8jXi.png)

When I try to do **update database from model** for this table, the `allocation_type` column is not generated in .net.

How can I map this custom data type column to my `.edmx` file? Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe you have to model this as a [complex type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680147(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got a workaround for this. i created a new view in postgresql for table that have custom data type and cast the columns into its primitive data type. this also work for column that have postgresql unique type such as array.